# Setting base-href on build Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

how do i set the base href on build?
I tried

```
--base-href /path/
--base-href=/path/
--base-href="/path/"
--base-href='/path/'
```

and none works

it keeps telling me `base-href should start and end with /`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This does the trick...

```
flutter build web --base-href "/path/"
```

Comment: what should I write in "path"? Please help :(.

Comment: For instance if you publish your flutter application at mysite.com/path/ you set it to "/path/". If you publish it directly to mysite.com you can omit the base href parameter.

Comment: This fails in Bash on Windows, but this works in PowerShell on Windows.

Comment: It seems like that in bash on Windows we have to escape the slashes?

Comment: Isn't there a file somewhere where you can set this and just run `flutter build web`? I searched but found nothing.

Comment: @GuiRitter looks like you can set it in `flutter/web/index.html` using `<base href="/path/">` https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation/url-strategies

Comment: @TBG Indeed, thanks! Just to make it clear for others, `flutter` in `flutter/web/index.html` refers to the project's root folder.

Answer (score 1):

Today I deployed a web build to my hosting.

Let's say `https://example.com/myapp/web/` but unfortunately, nothing was working. When I opened DevTools in Chrome  I saw that browser trying to reach `https://example.com/flutter.js` and some other files at site root. I did not understand what is going on until I saw

```
<base href="/">
```

After I removed the `base` tag everything worked fine.

Morality: just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Windows MSYS (git bash, mingw, etc) you should use env `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1`:

```bash
$ MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 flutter build web --release \
    --base-href="/openapi_generator_flutter/"
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are using git bash shell, you can automate it:

Example:

```
flutter build web
path="/webtest/"
sed -i "s|<base href=\".*\">|<base href=\"$path\">|g" build/web/index.html
```