# Flutter web deploying to custom domain not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, custom-domain

I am trying to upload my flutter web on the custom domain using `cPanel`.
Here is my custom domain.

[image: domain photo]

Here is how I have uploaded my files from `build->web`.

[image: folder photo]

But still I am getting following error when I try to visit my website.

[image: browser error]

Here is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--
      If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
      href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

      The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
      it to work correctly.

      For more details:
      * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

      This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
      the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
    -->
    <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

    <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="ali_patente_main">

    <meta name="google-signin-client_id"
          content="592741627721-4m52dnuaensfj8u2cqb3iijmlnr08t5n.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="g3hot9RVL3LWijecM2J-F-OOSxGE7Chne7lGt9t2_Xc"/>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

    <title>ali_patente_main</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
<script>
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyDROViVM7xDdXsxjHHwo2-NYeWQV23K54Q",
  authDomain: "ali-patente-e2bbc.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://ali-patente-e2bbc.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "ali-patente-e2bbc",
  storageBucket: "ali-patente-e2bbc.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "592741627721",
  appId: "1:592741627721:web:e86a3dabf0ebd37fd98c98",
  measurementId: "G-1JF7N5YZNG"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);


</script>
<script>
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
    var scriptLoaded = false;
    function loadMainDartJs() {
      if (scriptLoaded) {
        return;
      }
      scriptLoaded = true;
      var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
      scriptTag.src = 'main.dart.js';
      scriptTag.type = 'application/javascript';
      document.body.append(scriptTag);
    }

    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {

      window.addEventListener('load', function () {

        var serviceWorkerUrl = 'flutter_service_worker.js?v=' + serviceWorkerVersion;
        navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorkerUrl)
          .then((reg) => {
            function waitForActivation(serviceWorker) {
              serviceWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
                if (serviceWorker.state == 'activated') {
                  console.log('Installed new service worker.');
                  loadMainDartJs();
                }
              });
            }
            if (!reg.active && (reg.installing || reg.waiting)) {

              waitForActivation(reg.installing || reg.waiting);
            } else if (!reg.active.scriptURL.endsWith(serviceWorkerVersion)) {

              console.log('New service worker available.');
              reg.update();
              waitForActivation(reg.installing);
            } else {

              console.log('Loading app from service worker.');
              loadMainDartJs();
            }
          });


        setTimeout(() => {
          if (!scriptLoaded) {
            console.warn(
              'Failed to load app from service worker. Falling back to plain <script> tag.',
            );
            loadMainDartJs();
          }
        }, 4000);
      });
    } else {

      loadMainDartJs();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any step that I've missed?
Is there any thing that I've done wrong?

Comment: Can you share baseref on `index.html`

Comment: I have added it. Any valuable suggestion now?

Comment: you can try with providing custom `base href` while building for web

Comment: [this may help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70271429/10157127)

Comment: I tried <base href="/"> but it didn't work. Anything else?

Comment: flutter build web --base-href "/path/"
what should I write in place of "path"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243722/discussion-between-adil-naseem-and-yeasin-sheikh).