# Flutter Web: How to get base_href in dart code?

Tags: flutter

I know that base_href can be configured with below method.

command

```bash
flutter build web --base-href "/path/"
```

or

index.html

```html
<base href="/path/">
```

ref: [Setting base-href on build Flutter Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70271429/setting-base-href-on-build-flutter-web)

How to get this information(`/path/`) in my Dart code?

Example:
`--base-href "/foo/"`
URL: `http://localhost:8080/foo/some-route`

I want: `/foo/`
Uri.base.path: `/foo/some-route`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure we can get this from the `uri` directly. You could try load the html and get the `href` attribute from the `base` tag. The below snippet shows how to do that:

```dart
import 'dart:html' as html;

String? getBaseHref() {
  final allBaseTags = html.document.getElementsByTagName('base');
  if (allBaseTags.isNotEmpty) {
    // Get the 'href' attribute directly from the first base tag
    final hrefValue = (allBaseTags.first as html.Element).getAttribute('href');
    return hrefValue;
  }
  return null;
}
```

We get the base tags, read the first one and get the href attribute. Where it is not available we return null. However, we should always have this available as it is always set as `<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">` to allow one pass the `base href` as an arg.

Answer (score 1):

`Uri.base` says:

> The natural base URI for the current platform.
>
> When running in a browser, this is the current URL of the current page
> (from window.location.href).
>
> When not running in a browser, this is the file URI referencing the
> current working directory.

Comment: I want base_href, not current URL.  

Example:  
`--base-href "/foo/"`  
URL: `http://localhost:8080/foo/some-route`  

I want: `/foo/`  
Uri.base.path: `/foo/some-route`